# Control how your properties behave when the data get duplicated?

Tags: python, properties

Here's an illustration of the problem :

- create a property `my_name` on `bpy.types.Object`
- assign a name on a single object, let say "*Martin*"
- Duplicate this object
- All dupplicata will also be named "*Martin*", in fact, they will inherit all properties values from the original object.

How can we control our properties reacts when their data get duplicated?

for example, in this illustration i'd like to , add a **numerical suffix** automatically, or **reset the name** to an empty value, is there an easy way to do that? For example, by wrapping the object copy function?

Comment: I'm afraid we are forced to handle this scenario from a handler.. this is not a very elegant solution

Comment: can you show what python script you have come up with and tried?

Comment: i did not found an elegant solution to this problem unfortunately